# add to linked list help? c language only

Tags: c, linked-list

So I have this linked list and it works but only if you add one item to the list. Here is my code for it:

```
    struct node{
       char key[10];
       char content[20];
       struct node *next;
    };
    struct node *head=(struct node *) NULL;
    struct node *tail=(struct node *) NULL;

    struct node * initinode(char *key, char *content)
    {
     struct node *ptr;
     ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node ) );
      if( ptr == NULL )                       
         return (struct node *) NULL;        
      else {                                  
         strcpy( ptr->key, key );          
         strcpy(ptr->content,content);                       
           return ptr;                         
           }
     }
    void printnode( struct node *ptr )
    {
      printf("Key ->%s\n", ptr->key );
      printf("Contents   ->%d\n", ptr->content );
     }
    void printlist( struct node *ptr )
      {
         while( ptr != NULL )           
         {
           printnode( ptr );          
           ptr = ptr->next;            
         }
     }
    void add( struct node *new )  
    {
       if( head == NULL ) {     
         head = new;
         tail=new; 
       }                   
       else {
         tail->next = new;        
         tail->next=NULL;              

            }
    }
```

So when I try and add three items to the list and print it will only show the first item like these three:

```
     struct node *ptr;
    char *terminal="term";
        char *term;
        term=getenv("TERM");  
      ptr=initinode(terminal, term);
          add(ptr);
     //-----------------------
      char ccterm[20];
      char *ret, tty[40];
      char *currTerminal="tty";
     if ((ret = ttyname(STDIN_FILENO)) == NULL)
               perror("ttyname() error");
     else {
        strcpy(tty, ret); 
          }
      ptr=initinode(currTerminal, tty);
      add(ptr);

    //----------------------------------
     char cwd[1024];
     char *st="date";
     time_t t;
     char ti[30];
     time(&t);
     char date;
     date=t;
     sprintf(ti,"%s", ctime(&t));
     ptr=initinode(st, ti);
     add(ptr);
     printlist(ptr);
```

This brings me to my last question when I add any of these to the list it only outputs int values so how would I print out the string values in the list. I have tried modifying my code to male contents a string, but it never works out. Any advice is greatly appreciated and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your add function, you have this:

```
tail->next = new;        
tail->next=NULL;
```

when it should be

```
tail->next = new;
tail = new;
tail->next=NULL;
```

The other problem is in printnode. You should be using %s for a string when printing out the contents. %d is for ints.

Comment: thanks it fixed the int problem but I still can't seem to add things correctly to my list. when I make a string representation with sprintf like in the last item it does not add and It is still only adding one item to the list.

Comment: @Noob programmer, you need to printlist(head), not printlist(ptr) to get the whole list.

Comment: thank you so much everything you said has really helped me and has worked for my program.

Comment: @Noob programmer, if you don't need any more help with this question, then you should accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To print strings, you need to fix your `printnode` function.

```
printf("Contents   ->%s\n", ptr->content );
                      ^
```

It prints `int` values because you ask it specifically(`%d`) to print `int` values.

Justin has fixed the other problem with your add function.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not cast `malloc()` and `NULL` etc.
2. Problems in program:

   `tail->next = new;  //I am new list

    tail->next=NULL;   //I am nobody!`

You probably meant:

```
tail->next = new;
tail->next->next = NULL;
tail = tail->next;
```

Comment: thanks it fixed the int problem but I still can't seem to add things correctly to my list. when I make a string representation with sprintf like in the last item it does not add and It is still only adding one item to the list. Also what happens if you do cast malloc() and NULL please explain sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @Noobprogrammer in C it is considered bad practice if you cast the `malloc()` and `calloc` and `realloc` and `NULL` values.

Comment: @Aniket how do you use the malloc-ed memory without casting?

Comment: @Aniket nvm, I was going with C++'s stricter rules